# Cycle through Data Validation ; set range = Data validation list that is not based on a source of cells

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I know exactly what my problem is, but cannot find a solution.

I have two sheets, which run almost identical code, but the second sheet is a child of the first sheet's header.

Here is my code:

```
Dim inputRange, inrng2 As Range

 Dim c, d As Range
Set inputRange = Evaluate(ws2.Range("D1").Validation.Formula1)
 For Each c In inputRange

 temp = c.Value

     ws2.Cells(1, 4).Value = temp
    ws2.Activate
    ws2.PrintOut


   ws3.Activate

Set inrng2 = Evaluate(ws3.Range("D1").Validation.Formula1)


 For Each d In inrng2

 temp = d.Value

     ws3.Cells(1, 4).Value = temp
    ws3.Activate
    ws3.PrintOut
Next d
```

My issue is, inrng2 is giving me a type mismatch error.

this is because my data validation for the ws3 sheet is driven by code earlier in a different part of the sheet:

```
ThisWorkbook.ws3.Activate

ActiveSheet.Range("D1:E2").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=TClist
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True


End With
```

where TC list is a comma separated string driven by the ws2 header

so the

```
 Set inputRange = Evaluate(ws2.Range("D1").Validation.Formula1)
```

works because the formula is :='Team Codes'!$N$2:$N$6

but the

```
 Set inrng2 = Evaluate(ws3.Range("D1").Validation.Formula1)
```

does not work because the 'formula' is :

team1,team2,team3 etc

This printing element is the final peice of the puzzle to an long effort of building this sheet, and i am very happy with how the rest of the sheet performs. how can I get vba to cycle through each of the datavalidation items as they are listed?

thanks!

Comment: Use `Split` to break the list into an array and loop through that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @rory, I just needed a push in the right direction to break up my tunnel vision:

```
teamlist = ws3.Range("D1").Validation.Formula1
   tlsplit() = Split(teamlist, ",")



 For i = LBound(tlsplit) + 1 To UBound(tlsplit)

' +1 so you dont start at 0


     ws3.Cells(1, 4).Value = tlsplit(i)
    ws3.Activate
    ws3.PrintOut
Next i
```